# How to use wildcards in execv without system or bash (in c)?

Tags: ubuntu, wildcards, c

I would like to use

```
char *argv[] = {"rm", "-r", "/home/banana/Quest/*/", NULL};
execv("/bin/rm", argv);
```

in a C file to delete all directories in the Quest folder. But wildcards don't work. How can I do this without system or bash? I have heard of glob but it's a bit confusing.

I tried something like :

```
glob_t globbuf;
int err = glob("/home/solxius/modul2/petshop/*/", 0, NULL, &globbuf);
globbuf.gl_pathv[0] = "rm";
globbuf.gl_pathv[1] = "-r";
char *argv[] = {"rm", "/home/solxius/modul2/petshop/", NULL};
execvp("bin/rm", &globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You will have to use `glob` or `bash`. Read `man 3 glob;man 7 glob`. Ever since early Unix (V6+) wildcard expansion is done by the shell.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a pure C programming question and isn't connected to *nix or the UNIX/LINUX API or anything like that.

Comment: Now that I look closer, that snippet you added later is pretty close to the example in the man page: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/glob.3.en.html . All you need to do is tell it to reserve those two pointers for the fixed args of your command. And make sure it only finds directories. @terdon, btw [`glob()` is in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/glob.html) (honestly I thought some of the mods would migrate, but I'm not sure what sort of a response SO would have given anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `glob()` seems simple enough to use. Of course you could do it manually with e.g. `readdir()` and `fnmatch()`.

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* run as 'globtest "*.txt"' */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glob_t g;
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <pattern>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int ret = glob(argv[1], 0, NULL, &g);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("found %d matches:\n", (int) g.gl_pathc);
        for (int i = 0; g.gl_pathv[i]; i++) {
            printf("  %s\n", g.gl_pathv[i]); 
        }
    } else if (ret == GLOB_NOMATCH) {
        printf("no matches!\n");
    } else {
        printf("some error happened\n");
    }
}
```

Of course you'll still need to copy the (pointers to the) strings to the array passed to `execv()`/`execve()`.